# Hydra sometimes fails against my own router known password

Tags: passwords, router

Hydra sometimes fails against my own router known password. Sometimes confirms it was found, and sometimes returns unusual error code (empty). What does this means?

```
dione@saturno:~/misc$ hydra -l admin -p myknownpass 192.168.1.1 http-get -vV

Hydra v8.0 (c) 2014 by van Hauser/THC & David Maciejak - Please do not use in military or secret service organizations, or for illegal purposes.

Hydra (http://www.thc.org/thc-hydra) starting at 2014-10-04 18:24:28
[WARNING] You must supply the web page as an additional option or via -m, default path set to /
[DATA] max 1 task per 1 server, overall 1 tasks, 1 login try (l:1/p:1), ~1 try per task
[DATA] attacking service http-get on port 80
[VERBOSE] Resolving addresses ... done
[ATTEMPT] target 192.168.1.1 - login "admin" - pass "myknownpass" - 1 of 1 [child 0]
[80][www] host: 192.168.1.1   login: admin   password: myknownpass
[STATUS] attack finished for 192.168.1.1 (waiting for children to complete tests)
1 of 1 target successfully completed, 1 valid password found
Hydra (http://www.thc.org/thc-hydra) finished at 2014-10-04 18:24:29
```

---

```
dione@saturno:~/misc$ hydra -l admin -p myknownpass 192.168.1.1 http-get -vV

Hydra v8.0 (c) 2014 by van Hauser/THC & David Maciejak - Please do not use in military or secret service organizations, or for illegal purposes.

Hydra (http://www.thc.org/thc-hydra) starting at 2014-10-04 18:24:36
[WARNING] You must supply the web page as an additional option or via -m, default path set to /
[DATA] max 1 task per 1 server, overall 1 tasks, 1 login try (l:1/p:1), ~1 try per task
[DATA] attacking service http-get on port 80
[VERBOSE] Resolving addresses ... done
[ATTEMPT] target 192.168.1.1 - login "admin" - pass "myknownpass" - 1 of 1 [child 0]
[WARNING] Unusual return code:  for admin:myknownpass
[STATUS] attack finished for 192.168.1.1 (waiting for children to complete tests)
1 of 1 target completed, 0 valid passwords found
Hydra (http://www.thc.org/thc-hydra) finished at 2014-10-04 18:24:36
```

Comment: Hydra is pretty old.  I know [patator](https://github.com/lanjelot/patator) is actively developed  because it had a new release 9 days ago.  Does it have the same problem?

Comment: You are not specifying all the necessary parameters for http-get. You need to provide hydra with a way of telling wether it has a successful login. See http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/15298/how-to-use-http-get-form-in-thc-hydra. Also, hydra is old, but that does not necessarily mean it is less effective. Hydra is still extremely effective and efficient. Plus, according to the github page (https://github.com/vanhauser-thc/thc-hydra), vanhauser authored a commit only two days ago.

Comment: In fact, Hydra v8.0 was released in 2014. @735Tesla thanks, however, that post is related to the http-get-form login. This is Basic Authentication I guess. I don't know the reason why sometimes works and sometimes fails.

Comment: Have you tried to sniff this traffic? Bet you will see the difference there. I mean, if your interface sending same requests and gets different responses then it is more likely your router to blame, not hydra.

Comment: I'll check that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, that router's web server is not very well implemented, and vanhauser updated his code in order to handle it.
This was my issue (now closed),

https://github.com/vanhauser-thc/thc-hydra/issues/18